# Remove the first zeros in excel

Tags: excel, formula, substitution

I want to remove in Excel the first zeros from the following codes, the problem is that the zeros don't have the same pattern. What can I do to achieve this?

The codes before:
0000450D
00320A
0000107B
023B

I want the codes to be like this:
450D
320A
107B
23B

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to use VBA, insert the code below into a new module and on your sheet, use the function like `=ReplaceZeros(A1)`

```
Public Function ReplaceZeros(varVal As String)

varLeading = True

For i = 1 To Len(varVal)

    If Mid(varVal, i, 1) = "0" Then

        If varLeading = False Then

            varOutput = varOutput & Mid(varVal, i, 1)

        End If

    ElseIf Mid(varVal, i, 1) = " " Then

        varLeading = True
        varOutput = varOutput & Mid(varVal, i, 1)

    Else

        varLeading = False
        varOutput = varOutput & Mid(varVal, i, 1)

    End If

Next

ReplaceZeros = varOutput

End Function
```

This will simply cycle through the characters and remove leading zeroes from the start of the string, or following a space

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,"")),A1),255)
```